# При загрузки локального видео через iframe появляется атрибут autoplay

Tags: javascript, html5, видео, iframe

Я загружаю видео на страницу через  iframe

```
<iframe id="videoFrame" class="howPopup__youtube how__youtube"
        src=".assets/videofile.mp4"
        frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Когда оно отрисовывается то появляется тег  video с атрибутом  autoplay
Можно как-то сделать чтобы тег video появлялся без этого атрибута?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал для этих целей все таки тег `video`, но если нужно через `iframe`, то можно применить следующий хак, который при загрузке `iframe` обратится к первому дочернему элементу в `body` и уберет соответсвующий атрибут, разумеется код можно вынести отдельно и добавить дополнительную логику:

```
<iframe id="videoFrame" class="howPopup__youtube how__youtube"
  src=".assets/videofile.mp4"
  frameborder="0" 
  onload="this.contentWindow.document.body.children[0].autoplay=null">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Спасибо, iframe потому что некоторые видео грузятся с ютуба, а некоторые локально. А логика на фронте одна

Comment: Понятно, тогда да